# Non-resizable window swift

Tags: macos, swift, nswindow, window-resize, nsviewcontroller

I have a `NSViewController` named `Hardness`, and I need not to let user resize it. Of course, I can just resize it back every time the users tries, but is there any way just not to let user open a window to full screen, or to stretch the window?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

edit/update: **Xcode 10.2 • Swift 5**

NSWindow has a property called styleMask that allows you to control what kinds of control will be available to the user. If you don't want to allow the user to resize the window you have to remove the style mask .resizable using the mutating method `remove(member: NSWindowStyleMask)`. To enable it again you need to use the mutating method `insert(member: NSWindowStyleMask)`. Note that it will also disable the full screen mode for that window:

---

removing to disable:

```
window.styleMask.remove(.resizable)
```

inserting to enable

```
window.styleMask.insert(.resizable)
```

Sample

```
import Cocoa
class ViewController: NSViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var closable: NSButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var miniaturizable: NSButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var resizable: NSButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var titled: NSButton!
    lazy var window: NSWindow! = self.view.window
    func remove(_ member: NSWindow.StyleMask) {
        window.styleMask.remove(member)
    }
    func insert(_ member: NSWindow.StyleMask) {
        window.styleMask.insert(member)
    }
    @IBAction func toggle(_ sender: NSButton) {
        switch sender.state {
        case .on:
            switch sender {
            case closable: insert(.closable)
            case miniaturizable: insert(.miniaturizable)
            case resizable: insert(.resizable)
            case closable: insert(.closable)
            case titled: insert(.titled)
            default: break
            }
        case .off:
            switch sender {
            case closable: remove(.closable)
            case miniaturizable: remove(.miniaturizable)
            case resizable: remove(.resizable)
            case closable: remove(.closable)
            case titled: remove(.titled)
            default: break
            }
        default: break
        }
    }
}
```

[Sample Project](https://www.dropbox.com/s/se7wp9zdlx89o5t/WindowButtons.zip?dl=1)

Comment: I've written in the viewDidLoad this code: `self.view.window?.styleMask = NSClosableWindowMask | NSTitledWindowMask | NSMiniaturizableWindowMask` and that didn't work

Comment: Oh, this code needs to be in viewDidAppear, that worked, thank you!

Comment: `window.styleMask = [.closable, .titled, .miniaturizable] //Swift 3`

Answer (score 11):

I solved the same issue with the non-resizable window by one line of code in

```
override func viewDidAppear() {
    self.view.window?.styleMask.remove(NSWindowStyleMask.Resizable)
}
```

Comment: I like that better.

Answer (score 6):

The correct approach would be to use [bitwise operators](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AdvancedOperators.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH27-ID29).

**Disable** resize:

```
window?.styleMask &= ~NSResizableWindowMask
```

**Enable** resize:

```
window?.styleMask |= NSResizableWindowMask
```

Comment: Hi. Any ideas how to port it to Swift 3? `Binary operator '|=' cannot be applied to two 'NSWindowStyleMask' operands`

Comment: I don't know why this is so, but here is a workaround: `window?.styleMask = NSWindowStyleMask(rawValue: (NSWindowStyleMask.closable.rawValue | NSWindowStyleMask.titled.rawValue))`

Comment: It will be `window?.styleMask.update(with: NSWindowStyleMask.resizable)`.

Answer (score 2):

This answer may be of some help in addition to the current one. There's also a nice simple way to accomplish this by using `setHidden` with  `NSWindowZoomButton`

Setup the functionality as a sub-class of `NSWindow`:

**Objective-C**

```
#import "CustomWindow.h"

@implementation CustomWindow

- (void)awakeFromNib {

NSButton *zoomButton = [self standardWindowButton:NSWindowZoomButton];
[zoomButton setHidden:YES];

}

@end
```

**Swift**

```
import CustomWindow

class CustomWindow {

    func awakeFromNib() {
        var zoomButton: NSButton = self.standardWindowButton(NSWindowZoomButton)
        zoomButton.setHidden(true)
    }
}
```

Connect the custom class to your window in IB and the `Zoom` button should be now hidden!

Comment: shouldnt it be?                                                                                            class CustomWindow: NSWindow {
        override func awakeFromNib() {                                                      var zoomButton: NSButton = self.standardWindowButton(NSWindowButton.ZoomButton)!
            zoomButton.enabled=true
        }
    }                                                                                                                         i tried to do the same for close button but it wouldnt work..

Comment: @Do2: Try using  `self.standardWindowButton(NSWindowButton.CloseButton)?.hidden = true` ... I think apple changed it up a bit since I answered this question originally.

Comment: var closeButton: NSButton = self.standardWindowButton(NSWindowButton.CloseButton)! closeButton.hidden=true    ? I also tried to call the awakefromnib from the viewDidAppear of the viewcontroller  from the view It crashes due to nil while unwrapping an optional, any ideas?

Comment: Are you trying to hide the zoom button or close button? and in what version of swift, and OS X are you using? I'll post a more complete gist you can try shortly.

Comment: im using modal views so the close button disappears after the first segue, and then after 2-3 segues the minimise and resize are hidden but if you hover over them they show up, i would like all the buttons to be shown no matter how many segues are performed. swift 2.2 el capitan

Comment: @Do2: I hadn't done this with storyboards before, ( usually just nibs ) so I would recommend trying something like this with your windowcontroller: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/86596332f570ecbf2452b90077197264

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121678/discussion-between-do2-and-lll).

Answer (score 2):

A little more elegant solution for Swift 3, so that the | operator can be used:

```
public func | (left: NSWindowStyleMask, right: NSWindowStyleMask) -> NSWindowStyleMask {
    return NSWindowStyleMask(rawValue: left.rawValue | right.rawValue)
}
```