# OSX - Disable Fullscreen Mode from the zoom button?

Tags: objective-c, swift, macos, fullscreen, nswindow

I'm looking for either a setting option of `NSWindow` in XIB editor or via programmatically take I can disable the **fullscreen mode** feature in **OS X** when the user clicks the zoom button (green traffic light), as it does not work well with my UI design. (Instead, use it for normal window zooming.)

Anyone can give me some hints where to look for?

Comment: I don't see anything stupid here. It's just a simple question that if we can achieve such purpose. In some cases it's not a good idea to have things go fullscreen.

Comment: No. 1, if you are going to submit your app to Mac App Store, it will be rejected.  If it's not rejected, that will only be because they don't find the function that is not working.  No. 2, if there is a visible interface control, naturally, the user is going to click on it or whatever.  If it's not functional, then don't show it in the first place.

Comment: @ElTomato "No. 1, if you are going to submit your app to Mac App Store," can you show where have you read that?

Comment: @LeoDabus: I just added an answer that might be of help to you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33457584/499581. I seriously doubt Apple will reject your app, seeing as how they explain how to override it in the documentation :)

Comment: I'm also curious why they'd wanted to ban an app that does not need fullscreen mode. Zooming is fine, but fullscreen mode make things unusable in my situation. I'd wanted to know the answer anyways, MAS or not.

Comment: I agree with you on that completely; and would be interested to see where that is stated in the guidelines. Apparently all menubar apps should be rejected accordingly :p

Comment: I've no idea why it's considered duplicate. Anyways, I added the answer I figured out to my question.

Comment: Well I think the title and the part about the zoom button was what made it appear to be a duplicate. It wasn't exactly clear how you wanted to disable full-screen mode (either by a button or disabling the hot-keys, etc.)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Here's what I figured out.

To *change the behavior* of the zoom button to normal window zooming (not by hiding the button), change the window to "**Auxiliary**" will do.

[image: XIB Editor]

Attributes Inspector > Full Screen > Auxiliary Window

If there's a better answer to this, I'd be more than happy to accept that as the correct answer.

Comment: To do this programmatically: `[[self window] setCollectionBehavior:NSWindowCollectionBehaviorFullScreenAuxiliary];`

Answer (score 1):

For SwiftUI:

```swift
.onReceive(
    NotificationCenter.default.publisher(
        for: NSApplication.willUpdateNotification), perform: { _ in
            for window in NSApplication.shared.windows {
                window.collectionBehavior = .fullScreenAuxiliary
            }
})
```