# |= operator cannot be applied to two NSWindowMask operations

Tags: swift, operators

In swift 4 this fails

```
self.window.styleMask |= NSWindowStyleMask.fullSizeContentView
```

and I'd also like to undo

```
self.window.styleMask ^= NSWindowStyleMask.fullSizeContentView
```

as I would in objective-c

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30761996/swift-2-0-binary-operator-cannot-be-applied-to-two-uiusernotificationtype – OptionSet is used since Swift 2.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29339315/2303865

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Swift, `NSWindowStyleMask` (in Swift 4, `NSWindow.StyleMask`) is [`OptionSet`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/optionset). You need to use methods defined for [`SetAlgebra`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/setalgebra).

Swift 4:

```
self.window!.styleMask.formUnion(NSWindow.StyleMask.fullSizeContentView)

self.window!.styleMask.formSymmetricDifference(NSWindow.StyleMask.fullSizeContentView)
```

The code below compiles both in Swift 3 & Swift 4:

```
self.window!.styleMask.formUnion(.fullSizeContentView)

self.window!.styleMask.formSymmetricDifference(.fullSizeContentView)
```

Comment: Or `insert(.fullSizeContentView)` and (assuming that OP wants to remove, not to toggle) `remove(.fullSizeContentView)`

Comment: Ah, yes I would want to insert/remote aka toggle. What odd though is that this new way swells the window to include the title, but removal causes it to shift and resize, with the net affect that the window moves down and gets shorter?  I'd heard there was a sample which detailed how to use this. Perhaps that's all I need?

Answer (score 0):

This is ugly

```
self.window.styleMask = NSWindowStyleMask(rawValue: NSWindowStyleMask.fullSizeContentView.rawValue + panel.styleMask.rawValue)
```

seems to work?  The net affect is the content shrinks (by title height) when it's toggled.  So I might to back to what I had been using - .borderless